# Jboss Cache : what happens to an object which evicted from cache?

Tags: java, memory, jboss, jboss-cache, evict

If `Joss cache` evicts an object from a node, and the same object has reference to it from another object say `objB`. Does this condition causes any issue? Can `objB` manipulate on the evicted object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. JBoss Cache is smart enough to make a database call next time when objA is requested or when your code accesses objB which in turn needs objA.